# IE: Links with hash # disappear on the next page?

Tags: internet-explorer, hash

Didn't know that hashes in links disappear after opening that page.

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/#some-hash">link</a>
```

becomes

```
http://www.google.com/
```

It displays url with hash, in opened window hash is there for some time and then disappears.

Thanks ;)

```
**Update**
```

Why does hash disappear? It's normal behavior? How do you keep hashes?

```
$('a').live('click',function(){
 console.log($(this).attr('href'));
 window.open($(this).attr('href'));
 return false;
});

**Update**

<script type="text/javascript">alert(location.hash);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">alert(window.location.hash);</script>
```

Right after  alert is empty...

It's madness! I hate you Bill Gates! :D

```
**Update**
```

It works if opening directly without clicking on  link.

```
**Update**
```

Have checked on 3 PC, everywhere same effect... XP or Windows7, no matter.

Comment: You keep hashes in small plastic bags. Trust me I'm Dutch :-)

Comment: Hehe. I feel like IE doesn't like me. :D *sniff*

Comment: Which version of IE? in IE7 it doesn't happen so.

Comment: Both 7 and 8 versions i'll try to do it via javascript.

Comment: What can cause such bug?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this? I am unsure what I did but this just started happening on one of my sites, so I would be very happy to know if you ever found a fix?